# Can PoE cause interference with neighboring non-PoE Ethernet cables?

Tags: data-wiring, ethernet

I plan on upgrading my home Wireless Access Point in the near future and rather than running an extension cord to the location I was thinking about getting a WAP that supports Power Over Ethernet.

My concern is, since there is DC flowing thru the cable, will it cause interference with neighboring non-PoE Ethernet cables?

The PoE cable path will run parallel in a bundle to several Ethernet cables and cross another bundle of Ethernet cables.

Answer (score 14):

No, not a bit. Twisted pair cables are HIGHLY resistant to interference pickup. Furthermore, DC does not cause interference, since it is basically an unchanging current, so there's no change in magnetic fields from it to cause interference (other than when turned on, and off - and the twisted pair cables will reject that interference by design, anyway.)

I have many bundles of cables including POE cables in my work role. Interference is not a factor.

Comment: Just to clarify, there isn't any POE cable per se... Any cat5e or cat6 will do.

Comment: Though certain types of cat-X cables shouldn't be used, like copper-clad aluminum.

Comment: CCA (copper-clad aluminum) should not be used, (or bought) period. Horrible wire. A "POE cable," in context, is a Cat 5e or Cat6 or Cat6A cable that happens to be attached to a POE injector or switch and a device that uses POE.

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- yeah, CCA has no business being in network cables (it's fine for mains wiring, though, best I can tell)

Answer (score -1):

I just purchased reolink security cameras with POE. Whenever i turn on my POE, my freeview stops working on my TV because of the interference with the freeview ariel.

the POE cables and NVR were sitting near the ariel and TV so i moved the NVR and all cables to the first floor... the tv and ariel is on ground floor. As soon as i turned on the POE which is far away, the downstairs tv stops working again.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with all POE or just with this reolink i purchased.

Comment: The reolink guy go over to the ham radio section I think I remember them having  a solution to a problem like this awhile ago over there. Hope that helps bro