# Does low voltage cables cause interference against parallel cat5/6 ethernet cables

Tags: cables, ethernet

There is a similar question where someone is
building a new house and is planning to hardwire network cables into each room.

Can somebody run CAT5/6 cables parallel to low voltage  (5v, 9v, 12v, 15v) wires without introducing any general safety issues or losing much in connection quality?

Comment: You can run that sort of voltage [inside an ethernet cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) so it should indeed be quite safe. I'm not sure how much electrical noise low voltage cabling can generate though, so I can't answer the connection quality part of your question. Using a shielded & grounded cables would help, but it might be overkill.

Comment: Almost a duplicate. As noted there, Cat5e/6/6A cable (and the protocols that use them) are highly resistant to interference by design. Note that cable salesfolk try to upsell stuff that's not needed/useful despite that. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/92827/can-poe-cause-interference-with-neighboring-non-poe-ethernet-cables?rq=1

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What bothers electronic signals is oscillating magnetic fields.  DC power cables create an unchanging magnetic field like a refrigerator magnet.

However, if you are hauling 5 volts DC across a house, that's probably a mistake unless you are using huge wire.  Voltage drop will kill you...